# Flip the bits on the diagonal of a binary matrix

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix

The following code flips the bits of a binary-valued matrix.

I realise that the positions of diagonal elements (form {i,i}) can be easily generated with Table or another Mathematica function. I don't want to use this fact. I aim to learn about applying functions to elements in specific positions, using patterns to identify the positions.

The following code for flipping the bits on diagonal positions of a matrix has been written in that spirit:

Test to identify diagonal positions:

```
diagonalPositionTest[p_] := MatchQ[p, {i_, i_}]
```

Determining the positions of diagonal elements using MapIndexed:

```
helpMapIndexed[f_, m_] := MapIndexed[{#1, f[#2]} &, m, {2}]

matrixAnnotated = helpMapIndexed[diagonalPositionTest, M]
```

Flipping the diagonal-bits

```
matrixAnnotated /. {{x_, True} -> 1 - x, {x_, False} -> x}
```

The code can be tested on a binary-valued matrix:

```
M = IdentityMatrix[4] /. {0 :> RandomInteger[{0, 1}], 
   1 :> RandomInteger[{0, 1}]}
```

Can the above solution be coded in a different way?

I don't mean using the fact that diagonal positions are of a trivial form (eliminating the pattern-test).

I mean: is there a more direct route (or more efficient code) to produce the same result using a Mathematica command that

- makes use a pattern to identify particular positions
- with the aim to replace the elements in those selected positions with new elements
- (where these new elements are computed via a function application).

Or is MapIndexed the "right" approach (given the above aims)?

Comment: You can do something like `Do[M = MapAt[1 - # &, M, {i, i}], {i, 4}]`

Comment: I added a comparison between some of the methods, and it seems there may be some better solutions (eg faster, simpler) than the one currently accepted.

Comment: @HansOlo Thanks for the different timings. I like the alternatives (and their speed). They don't make use of patterns as discussed in the original question. The first two answers stay closer in spirit to the original question. Perhaps the others can be adapted as well. Not sure of the timing effect if they are adapted to use patterns so that more general cases (of flipping other selected elements) can be handled.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following seems reasonably clean:

```
M = RandomInteger[{0, 1}, {4, 4}]
(* {{0, 1, 1, 1}, {0, 1, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0}} *)

ReplacePart[M, {i_, i_} :> 1 - M[[i, i]]]
(* {{1, 1, 1, 1}, {0, 0, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1}} *)
```

My main issue with this is that `ReplacePart` doesn't give you access to the previous value at the affected position, so we have to extract it manually from `M`. (On the other side of the spectrum there is `MapAt`, which gets the previous value, but doesn't support pattern positions, so `ReplacePart` is definitely more suited)

Answer (score 8):

This is another way to do it

```
SetAttributes[flip, Listable]
flip[x_, 0] := x
flip[x_, 1] := 1 - x
flipDiagonal[m_?SquareMatrixQ] := flip[m, IdentityMatrix[Length[m]]]
```

to test

```
M = RandomInteger[{0, 1}, {6, 6}];
MatrixForm /@ {M, flipDiagonal[M]}
```

[image]

Comment: To fulfill the requirement of pattern-specified positions, you could generate the mark matrix using `SparseArray` instead of `IdentityMatrix`

Comment: I was just trying to flip the diagonal bits and ignored the bullet points.  Adding arbitrary requirements on an answer like that is just silly :-)

Comment: Thanks, I learned from both answers. Yours is a very elegant way to go about it.

Comment: @JasonB Where in the documentation can I read about an entire matrix (such as IdentityMatrix[Length[m]] in your code) being used as a template to determine positions at which to apply a listable function? I read up on listable but did not find a reference to this approach

Comment: Ignore the above comment: flip has two arguments. So the second argument guides the flipping of the bits based on the identity matrix. Ok.

Answer (score 6):

And yet another method using `BitXor[]`:

```
SeedRandom[1234];
m = RandomInteger[{0, 1}, {8, 8}];
Imn = IdentityMatrix[Length[m]];
```

which gives:

```
m // MatrixForm
BitXor[m, Imn] // MatrixForm
```

[image]

Also here's a quick time comparison of the various methods for large matrices (apologies as my Mathematica v11.2 doesn't support all the commands shown by other users). Note the timings are in secs and the runs were made on Windows 10.

```
SeedRandom[1234];
m = RandomInteger[{0, 1}, {200, 200}];
Imn = IdentityMatrix[Length[m]];

BitXor[m, Imn] // RepeatedTiming // First
(* 0.000051 *)

Abs[m - Imn] // RepeatedTiming // First
(* 0.00011 *)

LinearAlgebra`Private`SetMatrixDiagonal[m, 1 - Diagonal@m] // RepeatedTiming // First
(* 2.56*10^-6 *)

ReplacePart[m, {i_, i_} :> 1 - m[[i, i]]]//RepeatedTiming//First
(* 0.0091 *)

SetAttributes[flip, Listable]
flip[x_, 0] := x
flip[x_, 1] := 1 - x
flipDiagonal[m_?SquareMatrixQ] := flip[m,IdentityMatrix[Length[m]]]
flipDiagonal[m] // RepeatedTiming // First
(* 0.013 *)

(Set[m[[#, #]], Abs@(1 - #) &@m[[#, #]]] & /@ 
    Range@First@Dimensions@m) // RepeatedTiming // First
(* 0.00046 *)

m - Imn (2 m - 1) // RepeatedTiming // First
(* 0.00019 *)
```

From the methods tested, naively I'd say the `LinearAlgebra[]` method by @MichaelE2 and then `BitXor[]` are by far the fastest (albeit with the caveat that I didn't test a few of the methods as mentioned).

Answer (score 5):

Another way is by using a mask, which conveniently is now the IdentityMatrix:

```
SeedRandom[1234];
m = RandomInteger[{0, 1}, {8, 8}];
MatrixForm[m]
id = IdentityMatrix[Length[m]];
MatrixForm[m - id (2 m - 1)]
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

`` LinearAlgebra`Private`SetMatrixDiagonal `` does an in-place, non-functional-programming change (like a lot of LAPACK functions) and is quite speedy. Using @SHuisman's example:

```
SeedRandom[1234];
m = RandomInteger[{0, 1}, {8, 8}];

m // MatrixForm

LinearAlgebra`Private`SetMatrixDiagonal[m, 1 - Diagonal@m];
m // MatrixForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

In particular, it does not unpack the matrix, which `Listable` functions, `ReplacePart`, and `SubsetMap`† do (†`SubsetMap` is complicated: it unpacks something but perhaps not the whole matrix, and returns a packed matrix). Keeping the matrix packed can be an important factor in the performance of linear algebra applications; however, in small, short computations, it is not important.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `SubsetMap` to apply a function to the diagonal only.

```
n = 6;
SeedRandom[1];
M = RandomInteger[{0, 1}, {n, n}];
f1 = SubsetMap[Abs@(# - 1) &, M, {#, #} & /@ Range[n]]
MatrixForm /@ {M, f1}
```

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cccccc}
 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right),
\left(
\begin{array}{cccccc}
 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

---

**EDIT**

With `M` as defined above, evaluate to see the in-place change:

```
Dynamic[M // MatrixForm]

Set[M[[#, #]], Abs@(1 - #) & @M[[#, #]]] & /@ 
  Range@First@Dimensions@M;
```

Answer (score 2):

This might be too simple for SE mathematica, but I would just use subtraction and absolute value:

```
m1 = RandomInteger[{0, 1}, {6, 6}];
m2 = m1 - IdentityMatrix[6];
m3 = Abs[m2];

m1 // MatrixForm
m2 // MatrixForm
m3 // MatrixForm
```

Here's the output:

[image]